# How to wait for a promise when receiving an image from Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, async-await, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an app using React Native and store information about users in a collection called "User" on Firestore. Each user has a profile picture url stored in the collection, and I want to display multiple user images on the same page. I am struggling, however, to get this to work due to having to wait for Promises to return.

I have tried storing the url in a state variable when it is retrieved, however, this would involve creating loads of state variables due to the number of images I want to display. I then tried using async/await and then statements but the images won't load due to the promises not returning in time.

```
async getImg(user_id) {
    return await firebase.firestore().collection('User').doc(user_id).get()
        .then(user => {return user.data().image})
```

```
render() {

      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}> 
          <Image source={{uri: this.getImg('rwWa39Y6xtS1nZguswugODWndqx2') }} style={{ ... }} />
          <Image source={{uri: this.getImg('HQkCoChUe5fkZrHypYdRnrw66Rp2') }} style={{ ... }} />

      </SafeAreaView>
    );

  }
```

The above code is my latest attempt and it returns the following error due to a promise being returned instead of the string url.

```
You attempted to set the key `_65` with the value `1` on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the use of [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) with the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method.

By doing as follows:

```
async getImg(user_id) {
    const userSnapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('User').doc(user_id).get()
    return userSnapshot.data().image;
}
```

you will declare an asynchrnous `getImg()` function.

I don't know react-native so I don't know if it would work by using it in

```
<Image source={{uri: this.getImg('rwWa39Y6xtS1nZguswugODWndqx2') }} style={{ ... }} />
```

---

But @VolkanSahin45 solution, adapted as follows, should work:

```
async getImg(user_id) {
    const userSnapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('User').doc(user_id).get()
    this.setState({
      img: userSnapshot.data().image;
    })
}
```

---

Note that it would be good to handle errors with `try/catch` as follows:

```
async getImg(user_id) {

  try {
    const userSnapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('User').doc(user_id).get()
    this.setState({
      img: userSnapshot.data().image;
    })
  } catch (error) {
    this.setState({
      img: 'default_user_img.png';
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

getImg function returns Promise. Instead you can save img to state and render if there is img.

```
async getImg(user_id) {
  return await firebase.firestore().collection('User').doc(user_id).get()
    .then(user => {
        this.setState({
          img: user.data().image 
        })
      }
    )
}

render() {
  const { img } = this.state;
  return(
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}> 
      img && <Image source={{ img }} style={{ ... }} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. In this solution where would I actually call the getImg function? Especially as I want to display multiple images?

Comment: you can call in componentDidMount() @JoshuaZeltser